# Raf'ol yadayn when I am praying behind a imam of different madhab

Tags: salat, jamaat, madhhab

I'am used to do raf'ol yadayn in prayer... but when I am praying  behind an imam, can I do rafol yadayn when imam didn't?
or shouldn't I do that and need to follow the imam?
If I do so, will my salat be weak?

Answer (score 1):

The issue of raf'ol yadayn is not of whether it is permissible but of whether it is more virtuous. All Imams agree that it is permissible.

Suppose Imam is following Hanafi fiqh and not doing raf'ol yadayn, while you are following Shafai fiqh and doing raf'ol yadayn. There is absolutely no problem in you doing raf'ol yadayn while Imam doesn't. Here is a [fatwa](http://www.darulifta-deoband.com/home/en/Salah-Prayer/151280) by Darul-Uloom Deoband in this regard. The converse is also true. If the Imam is doing raf'ol yadayn and you are not (as per respective madhabs), then also there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that even if the imam doesn’t.

Comment: Always back-up this kind of claims with Qur'an or Sahih Hadith. Otherwise carries no weight. People like me will think you just heard it "somewhere", or it's just your opinion.

Comment: @Marwan But then you won't be "following" the Imam right???

Comment: @Ahmed In that case if the imam doesn’t pray according to sunnah for example, he doesn’t move his index finger in Tashahhud or doesn’t do the mutawarrikan position with his feets then even you have to leave the sunnahs? Of course the answer is no. You do the sunnahs even if the imam doesn’t do it.

Comment: @MarwanAnsari I guess your point raises the issue of can one pray behind an imam of a different madhab! Allah knows best. I hope we find an answer.

Comment: @Ahmed Truly Allah knows best. My personal opinion is that we can pray behind anyone who is a Muslim. Doesn't matter what madhab the imam belongs to.